# producing UTF-8 character by its code in Lazarus

Tags: string, lazarus

How do I convert from '\342\204\226' (octal), 0xE2 0x84 0x96 (hex), to '№' character in Lazarus?

I can use notation    edit3.caption:=#$E2#$84#$96 for constants, but I need it to work for variables.
What function should I use?

Handling letters is easy:

```
var r1, r2: integer
begin
  edit3.caption:=#$D0#$A0; 
  edit3.caption:=chr(r1)+chr(r2);
end;
```

both put expected 'Р' into the edit control.

Chr(r1)+Chr(r2)+Chr(r3) produces some unexpected symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the unicode value for that char is $2116, which is within the BMP, so a cast to widechar works:

```
edit3.caption:=widechar($2116);
```

or using chr:

```
edit3.caption:=chr($E2)+chr($84)+chr($96);
```

if you have trouble with variables, try making r1..r3 of type BYTE.

Comment: R1, r2, r3 of type Byte works the same way as Integer - some unexpected character is displayed. Typecasting 3 constants produces expected character. Will try using widechar function.